# How to call methods in React Native MapView?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I want call a method for the MapView component found in the docs. [Here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#methods)

I have absolutely no idea how to do it.

```
const Map = props => {
const mapRef = useRef();
const random = () => {
    console.log(mapRef);
    console.log(mapRef.current.getCamera());
}

return <MapView ref={mapRef} onClick={random()} style={styles.mapStyle}  provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} region={props.region} />;
```

};

This is what I tried based on what I found online but I keep getting undefined is not an object (evaluating 'mapRef.current.getCamera')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's going on here is that you are calling random function when the component is rendered and at this point the mapRef is null.

The other thing is, as I know, React Native components doesn't have onClick methods, in mobile development it is called onPress.

So you need to change your `onClick={random()}` to `onPress={random}` look that I erased the parentheses and changed the name of the method.

look at this example

```
export default function App() {
  const mapRef = useRef(null);
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  const handleMapPress = () => {
    const region = {
      latitude: 37.78825,
      longitude: -122.4324,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421
    };
    mapRef.current.animateToRegion(region); // Here I'm using one of the map methods
  }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{text}</Text>
        <MapView ref={mapRef} onPress={handleMapPress} style={styles.mapStyle} />
      </View>
    );
}
```

You can see it working in this [expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/@atabord/basicmapviewexample)